# Layout is getting pushed up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very simple layout that i designed to achieve the tool bar at the top of the screen. I am using weights here to fit all devices. Giving like 11 to the tool bar and 89 to the content body. That will fit all screens no matter what.

**Problem**:

I have a scroll view inside the content body and inside that scroll view i have like 4 `EditText` views. When i click the last `EditText` to type into it my layout gets pushed up specially the tool bar for which i have to use weights. 
Now please don't tell me not to use weights, just tell me how can i fix it. how can i stop the layout pushing up? Just like Gmail Client. when you are typing the header is not pushed up, stays there that you can save or send the email.

[image]

**Main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffe234"
            android:layout_weight="11" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Memories" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="89" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:minLines="6"
                        android:ems="10" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `weight ="0.11"` and `weight ="0.89"`
instead of
`weight ="11"` amd `weight ="89"` in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you want you add edit or add the android:windowSoftInputMode.  Then set it to adjustNothing, if you don't want the screen to adjust.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing">
</activity>
```

**Documentation**

> android:windowSoftInputMode

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

> adjustNothing  0x30    Don't resize or pan the window to make room for the soft input area; the window is never adjusted for it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode

Comment: Got any documentation on the `adjustNothing´-flag? Never heard of it, and can't find it on the official site.

Comment: @Ole I just posted the documentation of android:windowSoftInputMode but I didn't come across the `adjustNothing´-flag.  Which is odd because it should be there.  I will keep looking to find out more.  It has me curious.

Comment: @Ole just posted the  documentation on adjustNothing´-flag.  Have a look at it.  There are some other options as well.

Comment: Ah, thanks! `android.R.attr` is hardly documentation though :P  Does `adjustNothing` work for all api-levels?

Comment: @Ole all the way down to API 3

Comment: Added the flag in Activity Tag in menifest but still layout is getting pushed

Comment: @UsmanRiaz Okay, that is odd because it should not adjust anything.  Is that image in your question what you are trying to accomplish or what is happening? And are you adding the toolbar within the xml ?

Comment: Yes, a tool bar in xml. In the image when keyboard is displayed the tool bar stays there and you can scroll the content

Answer (score 0):

The layout is pushing up because scroll view adjusts to the entire screen when input method appears.

Try using ScrollView's property [isScrollContainer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:isScrollContainer) by setting it to false.

It should look like the following:

```
...
     <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:minLines="6"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
...
```

If this does not help consider setting proper [windowSofInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) in your activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I used that property but is still the same plusScroll view is not because scroll view is in the content are which is 89% of the total.

Comment: Shouldn't the LinearLayout have layout_height set to "wrap_content"? It is a child of ScrollView. Set it to "wrap_content" and let me know if that helps, please